# Eiffel - How do I make my classes readable?

Tags: linked-list, eiffel, readable

I'm new to Eiffel and I'm trying to use the LINKED_LIST class for organizing instances of other class "MONOMIO" I've made. I added a function for ordering this elements and I use the remove and the cursor movement features and when I try to execute the code it raises an exception saying that the objects contained should be readable and writable. I would like to know how to do it, this is my class:

```
class
    MONOMIO

feature --Initialization 
    make (coef:INTEGER; expX:INTEGER; expY:INTEGER)
    do
            coeficiente := coef
            exponenteX := expX
            exponenteY := expY
    end
feature
    evaluar(valX: INTEGER; valY: INTEGER): REAL_64
            do
                    Result := coeficiente*(valX^exponenteX)*(valY^exponenteY)
            end;
    coeficiente: INTEGER;

    exponenteX: INTEGER;

    exponenteY: INTEGER;


feature --setter
    set_coeficiente(val: INTEGER)
            do
                coeficiente := val
            end;
end
```

I think the exception raises because of this feature I've made for a class that has as a feature the LINKED_LIST[MONOMIO] and it's called "contenido":

```
simplificar
    local
        tamanio_polinomio: INTEGER -- Número de monomios que tiene el polinomio
        contador: INTEGER
        monomio_a_comparar: MONOMIO -- Auxiliar
        coeficiente_total:INTEGER -- Auxiliar
        indice_monomio_en_revision:INTEGER
    do
        from
            contenido.start
            indice_monomio_en_revision := 0
            tamanio_polinomio := contenido.count
        until
            indice_monomio_en_revision = tamanio_polinomio
        loop
            contenido.start
            contenido.move (indice_monomio_en_revision)
            monomio_a_comparar := contenido.item

            from
                contador := indice_monomio_en_revision
                coeficiente_total := monomio_a_comparar.coeficiente
                contenido.forth
            until
                contador = tamanio_polinomio
            loop
                if
                    (monomio_a_comparar.exponentex = contenido.item.exponentex) and
                    (monomio_a_comparar.exponentey = contenido.item.exponentey)
                then
                    coeficiente_total := coeficiente_total + contenido.item.coeficiente
                    contenido.remove -- Mueve el cursor a la derecha
                    tamanio_polinomio := tamanio_polinomio - 1
                    contador := contador - 1
                else
                    if
                        not contenido.islast
                    then
                        contenido.forth
                    end

                end
                contador := contador + 1
            end
            contenido.start
            contenido.move (indice_monomio_en_revision)
            contenido.item.set_coeficiente (coeficiente_total)
            indice_monomio_en_revision := indice_monomio_en_revision + 1
        end
    end;
```

I hope anyone can help me with this problem. Thanks.

Comment: The class looks OK, I guess the issue is in the code that works with LINKED_LIST. Can you show it and tell us what is the exact error you get? Is it a compile time error or a run-time error?

Comment: @AlexanderKogtenkov It's an exception raised on run-time it says "readable: PRECONDITION_VIOLATION raised" and it's due to a requirement of LINKED_LIST that asks for the object contained to be readable

Comment: Would you show the code that leads to the exception, please? (`readable` is a name of precondition subclause, it is not related to your class `MONOMIO`.)

Comment: @AlexanderKogtenkov sure, when the exception raises it shows me this, it's the LINKED_LIST code for its feature "item":
                `item: G
   -- Current item
  require -- from TRAVERSABLE
   not_off: not off
  require -- from ACTIVE
   readable: readable
  do
   check
     attached active as a
   then
    Result := a.item
   end
  end`

Comment: I mean your code, not the code of `LINKED_LIST`. I believe the issue is that you try to access an item beyond the list.

Comment: @AlexanderKogtenkov Oh sorry, I edited the question, there's the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a list with 1 element. Then we enter the outer loop and move to the first element. Then we execute `contador := indice_monomio_en_revision` that is still `0` at this point and do `contenido.forth`. Now we are beyond the list because there is only one element. However `contador = tamanio_polinomio` is false (`0 = 1`), so we enter the inner loop and try to retrieve the second (non-existing) item. BOOM!

Other issues include:

- There are multiple calls like `contenido.start` followed by `contenido.move`. You could use a single call to `go_i_th` instead.
- Instead of counting number of items in the list I would look at the feature `after`. It tells when you reach an end of the list. It would simplify the logic of your loop (e.g. the call to `islast` would be removed) and let you to remove some local variables.

Taking the last point into account I would write the inner loop condition as

```
contenido.after
```

At least this would avoid the crash you experience. As to the logic, you may need to check features `start`, `after`, `forth` and `remove` to see what effect they have. The usual way to write loops in such cases is like

```
from
    l.start
until
    l.after
loop
    ... -- Use l.item
    l.forth
end
```

In case of `remove` probably you do not need to call `forth`.

Comment: But doesn't the move feature move the cursor "i" positions to the right? I meant to let it in zero because then, on the first iteration, would remain in the same position according to what I'm understanding. Correct me if I'm wrong please. An thanks for the advices!

Comment: You are right, I confused it with `go_i_th`. I hope the current explanation is bug free. )